# Android Emulator doesn't work on Linux Fedora 22 beta

Tags: android

I can't launch x86 or x86_64 android emulator on Fedora Linux 22. I've tried a bit of images, including 5.01, 5.1.1, 4.2 & 4.4.something.

Currently, Arm version runs perfectly fine, just pretty much slow, which is annoying.

I have kvm module loaded:

```
➜  ~  lsmod|grep kvm
kvm_intel             159744  0 
kvm                   491520  1 kvm_intel
```

But x86 emulator just won't run. All I see is black screen.

Console output is empty as well. Not sure where to find logs, if any of them exist.

According to htop, emulator process is eating a bit of mem (as I've setted it up for it - 1Gb) and 100% of one CPU core.

Last time if that matters I've waited for may be 10 minutes before deciding that this isn't worth it. 
Not sure what info can I add to this. If anything helpful can be found to debug the problem, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foudn this comment on google code:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=174557#c10
Bios Works for me.

> I cannot speak for Google, who decides when to issue a new release of
>   the emulator (SDK Tools). But for people who need this fix now, it is
>   possible to manually apply it to their Android SDK installation:
>
> 1. Download the attached bios.bin. It is the same file that I just uploaded to https://android-review.googlesource.com/159501 (still
>      under review).    To download from the review, use the following link
>      instead:
>      https://android-review.googlesource.com/cat/159501%2C1%2Cx86/pc-bios/bios.bin%5E0
> 2. Make a backup of $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin ($ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is the Android SDK installation directory).
> 3. Copy the downloaded bios.bin to $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/lib/pc-bios/.

Comment: Congratulations! Consider pasting here part that helped you. SE is site aimed for Q&A style, and if your link goes down, the answer is lost.